# echo PHP from var_dump(JSON) e.g [''address"] and ["network"]

Tags: php, json

Here is the JSON result and I will like to get fetch out `["address"]` and `["network"]` using PHP

```
array(2) {
  ["status"]=>
  string(7) "success"
  ["data"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["network"]=>
    string(3) "BTC"
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(20)
    ["address"]=>
    string(34) "3DHSXwP49f6iLLfQXUQTFxPcedJdy4v8ii"
    ["label"]=>
    string(7) "ndaga81"
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not json, though. That already seem to be converted to a PHP array, so just fetch it like you normally would: `$address = $data['data']['address']` and so on.

Comment: Ok... Noted and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode the `json` and then get the data based on indexes

```
$array = json_decode($json,true);

echo $array['data']['network'];
echo $array['data']['address'];
```

***Sample output:-*** https://eval.in/1005728

Reference:-

[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly for me. Problem Solved. Kudos

Comment: @Babken glad to help you :):)